# Count and Replace Conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The requirements I have are as follows:
-names of all recording artists
-number of rock songs each artist sings
-list ordered so that the artist with the least number of rock songs appears first

*Note that some artists may not sing any rock songs, but should still be included in the list.

This should be done in a single query that obtains these results.

Make sure to eliminate unneeded columns from the result set, and to name your columns something user‐friendly and human readable.

This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT recording_artist.artist_name AS "Artist Name", Musical_genre.musical_genre AS "Genre",
        COUNT(Song.song_id) AS "Number of Songs"                         
FROM Album
JOIN recording_artist
    ON recording_artist.recording_artist_id = album.recording_artist_id
JOIN musical_genre
    ON musical_genre.musical_genre_id = album.musical_genre_id
JOIN Song 
    ON Album.album_id = Song.album_id                                                              
GROUP BY recording_artist.artist_name, Musical_genre.musical_genre      
ORDER BY "Number of Songs" ASC
```

Which shows me the 2 artist names who have rock songs, the column showing rock genre, and the number of rock songs each artist sings.

I can't figure out how to actually show those without rock songs as having 0 rock songs.

If I remove the WHERE command, it shows all songs and their count within each song genre, but still no way of setting anything but rock to 0. That's what I need help understanding.

EDIT: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

**EDIT: This is the output with the edit in red of what I need it to be. I need the total # of songs to represent the # of rock songs, and if the singer doesn't sing rock songs, I still need to list them and their value for # of songs to be 0 or NULL.**

[output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohSFG.png)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: The `where` condition on the outer joined table turns the outer join into an inner join. Move the condition ` Musical_genre.musical_genre = 'Rock'` into the join

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT recording_artist.artist_name AS "Artist Name", Musical_genre.musical_genre AS "Genre",
        COUNT(Song.song_id) AS "Number of Songs"                         
FROM Album
JOIN recording_artist
    ON recording_artist.recording_artist_id = album.recording_artist_id
LEFT JOIN musical_genre
    ON musical_genre.musical_genre_id = album.musical_genre_id
       AND Musical_genre.musical_genre = 'Rock
LEFT JOIN Song 
    ON Album.album_id = Song.album_id                                   
GROUP BY recording_artist.artist_name, Musical_genre.musical_genre      
ORDER BY "Number of Songs" ASC
```